# pulse stretching

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I have one problem, I am working on ADC signals and the type of square wave generally obtained has rise and fall time of 10ns roughly and stable level time of 80ns, so in total 100ns ON time. The next sample comes after 50ms approx . For computational purpose I have to stretch the pulse. Hence I am using a peak detector circuit with suitable RC network.  Currently I am using OPA657N and 1N4148WT diode. The critical part is that the input signal amplitude varies from 100mV to 5 volts . So diode will be a problem in peak detector. It would be helpful if you could suggest me  circuit or application specific opamp(part number).[image: peak detector circuit]

Comment: Why do you think the diode will be a problem? It is inside the feedback loop of the op amp which will compensate for the forward voltage drop.

Comment: Exactly - I've used this circuit for doing exactly what you want it for. I used a BAS16 though - it has slightly better reverse recovery that 1N4148.